# Delegates.observable() is not getting notified when using MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use `Delegates.observable()` in order to get notified when a change on a `MutableList` has happened.

```
val items: MutableList<Item> by Delegates.observable(startingItems) {
        _, old, new ->
        Log.e("observable", "${old.size}  -> ${new.size}")
    }
```

but nothing is happening whenever i try to remove nor add something to the list. I mean there's no trace of the log in the Logcat as it's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) state:

> **Observable**
>
> `Delegates.observable()` takes two arguments: the initial value and a handler for modifications. **The handler gets called every time we assign to the property** (after the assignment has been performed). It has three parameters: a property being assigned to, the old value and the new one.

In your case, you do not assign to `items`, you only add to the existing instance. The callback never gets invoked.

Suggestion: Use a mutable property with a read-only `List` and reassign it when a new element is being added:

```
var items: List<String> by Delegates.observable(mutableListOf()) { _, old, new ->
    println("changed")
}

//add like this:
user.items += "new val"
```

The `plus` operator does not call `add` on the list but creates a new instance with all old elements plus the new one.

Comment: How about when an item gets deleted from the list ? i cannot see a way to make that works also !

Comment: e.g. with `-=` operator

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this problem and it's actually 'cuz `Delegates.observable()`  only observes changes to the variable, not to the object stored in that variable.